# Pass properties over from one Construct to another with CDK before synth runs

Tags: aws-cdk

I've got two Constructs being created in one Stack, and during synthesis I would like to merge a bunch of properties and use the merged result.

The reason for this is to split creation of resources into a specific look in the Stack. In other words, I want to initialize two Constructs in the one Stack, but when CDK deploys the stack, I would like properties from both to be merged, with the resource(s) created in one of the Stacks, (`Environment` in my example below) being able to use the merged properties from both Constructs.

Here is where I've got to so far, but when running a `cdk synth` the resulting `someProperties` object does not reflect the items I've sent through from my `ExampleThing` Construct that was initialized in the same Stack.

```js
export class IExampleEnvironment extends Construct {

    readonly someId?: string;

}

export interface ExampleProps {
    readonly environment: Environment;

    readonly a: string;

    readonly b: string;
}

export class Environment extends IExampleEnvironment {

    private someProperties: any;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id);

        new ExampleResourceThatUsesSomeProperties(this, 'Example' { 
            foo: this.someProperties // this is where I would like to use some properties that are brought in from another Construct (in the same stack as Environment)
        });

    }

    public addSomeProperties(someProps: ExampleProps) {
        this.someProperties = { A: someProps.a, B: someProps.b };
    }

}


export class ExampleThing extends Construct {
    
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: ExampleProps) {

        super(scope, id);

        props.environment.addSomeProperties(props);

    }
}



// Creating the Stack...

const environment = new Environment(this, 'Environment', { someId: "123" });
const exampleThing = new ExampleThing(this, 'ExampleThing', props);
```

Currently, I'm using a reference to the `Environment` property sent in, and then calling the internal `addSomeProperties()` method on it, hoping that would work. I suspect this is my issue, but I'm not sure of how to achieve this.

The important thing here is that the `Environment` stack must be created first, as the `ExampleThing` stack needs to supply a `environment` property as part of its `ExampleProps` and pass the Environment in for that.

Is there a better way that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'll admit this is a very niche requirement, and not really the way CDK is meant to be used, but I wanted to get this very specific use case working.

I dug in a little more and found that it is possible by overriding the `prepare()` method in the Construct. Here is my working example, which shows how one construct can create an S3 bucket, and another can update this instance's S3 bucket purely by creating an instance and passing in the other instance:

**thing.ts**:

```js
import { Construct } from "@aws-cdk/core";
import { Foo } from "./foo";


export interface ExampleThingProps {

    readonly foo: Foo;

    readonly a: string;

    readonly b?: string;
}

export class ExampleThing extends Construct {
    
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: ExampleThingProps) {

        super(scope, id);

        props.foo.addSomeProperties(props);
        

    }
}
```

**foo.ts**:

```js
import { Construct, StackProps } from "@aws-cdk/core";
import * as s3 from "@aws-cdk/aws-s3";
import { ExampleThingProps } from "./thing";
import { IBucket } from "@aws-cdk/aws-s3";

export class IExampleFoo extends Construct {

    readonly someId?: string;
}

export interface FooProps {

    bucketName: string;
}

export class Foo extends IExampleFoo {

    private someProperties: any;
    private theBucket: IBucket;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: FooProps) {
        super(scope, id);

        this.someProperties = { A: props.bucketName };

        this.theBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'ExampleBucket', {
            bucketName: this.someProperties.A
        });

    }

    prepare() {
        const firstBucket = this.node.tryFindChild("ExampleBucket");
        if (firstBucket) {
            console.log('found first bucket node: ' + firstBucket.node.uniqueId);
            const removed = this.node.tryRemoveChild(firstBucket.node.id);
            console.log('removed the found node: ' + removed);
        }
        this.theBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'ExampleBucket', {
            bucketName: this.someProperties.A
        });
    }

    public addSomeProperties(someProps: ExampleThingProps) {
        console.log('updates the existing properties...');
        this.someProperties = { A: someProps.a, B: someProps.b };
    }

}
```

**Usage**:

```js
const foo = new Foo(this, 'Foo', {
   bucketName: "this-is-the-name-set-from-foo-construction"
});

const thing = new ExampleThing(this, 'Thing', {
   foo: foo,
   a: "shiny-new-name"
});
```

If you don't initialize a new `ExampleThing` then the bucket will be named **this-is-the-name-set-from-foo-construction**.

If you initialize a new `ExampleThing`, then the bucket's name will be changed for synthesize (and will apply in a `cdk diff` or `deploy` and be named **shiny-new-name**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to create dependencies between the resources, here is an example

```
const app = new App();

const myFirstStack = new MyFirstStack(
  app,
  stackNameone
);
const mySecondStack = new MySecondStack(
  app,
  stackNametwo
);
mySecondStack.addDependency(myFirstStack, "Depends on resources");
```

You can do this with most resources in CDK so whichever resources you want created first add it as a dependency like the above example.

Comment: Thanks for this - however I'm not looking to add a dependency between more than one stack. I have only got one stack, and what I am trying to do is use two resources (Constructs) inside the stack. One resource updates the properties on the other resource and when the stack deploys those properties are used.

Comment: Have you tried that add dependency method on the constructs. Or you could try return something from one construct and pass it into the other one?

Comment: I did try add dependency using the constructs within the stack, but no dice unfortunately. I have managed to find a workaround for my use case by overriding prepare() though. I'll post an answer shortly. Thanks for the suggestions.